# Cakephp Admin section in separate folder

Tags: php, cakephp-2.3

I'm developing an web application in use Cakephp 2.5 and want to separate the fronted and admin area. I create a admin folder under controller but unfortunately, I don't know how to route it in.

Please kindly help for.

Answer (score 0):

```
    // Put this in app/Config/bootstrap.php
    App::build(array(
        'Model' => array(
            ROOT.DS.APP_DIR.DS.'Model'.DS.'TEST'.DS,
        ),
        'Controller' => array(
            ROOT.DS.APP_DIR.DS.'Controller'.DS.'TEST'.DS,
        )
    ));
    // Put this in app/Config/routes.php
    Router::connect('/TEST/', array('prefix' => 'TEST','TEST' => true,'controller'=>'default'));
    // You should have in app/Controller/TEST/defaultController.php
    // And then you can do the redirect when logging it like :
    $this->redirect(array('TEST' => true,'controller' => 'default'));
```